# LaTeX multirow package conflicts

Tags: tables, multirow

I am using the multirow package with the following packages in `report` document class;

```
\usepackage[figuresright]{rotating}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{multirow, array}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes,arrows}
\usepackage{graphicx,caption,subfigure}
\usepackage{algorithm,algpseudocode}
\usepackage{amsmath,amsfonts,amssymb}
\usepackage{epstopdf}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage{lscape}
```

I am unable to compile with error as follows:

```
! Undefined control sequence.
\@xmultirow ...\advance \@tempdima #2\bigstrutjot
\setbox 0\hbox {\vtop to \...
l.561 }
```

What are the conflicting dependencies? This is my table structure:

```
\scalebox{0.9}{
\begin{tabular}{|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|}
\hline
\multirow{2}[0]{*}{S. No.} & \multicolumn{1}{|c|}{\multirow{2}[0]{*}{Subject}} & \multicolumn{1}{|c|}{\multirow{2}[0]{*}{Session}} & \multicolumn{1}{|c|}{\multirow{2}[0]{*}{Freq Band}} & \multicolumn{1}{|c|}{\multirow{2}[0]{*}{Our Approach}} & \multicolumn{6}{|c|}{Values}        \\

      & \multicolumn{1}{|c|}{} & \multicolumn{1}{|c|}{} & \multicolumn{1}{|c|}{} & \multicolumn{1}{|c|}{} & Ours & xxxx & xxxx  & xxxx* & xxx* & \multicolumn{1}{|c|}{xxx*} \\
      \hline
      \hline
```

Comment: from your code snippet is impossible find cause for your error. in standard document class article and simple table it works fine:  `\documentclass[12pt]{article}\usepackage[figuresright]{rotating} 
\usepackage{tikz}\usepackage{multirow, array}\usetikzlibrary{shapes,arrows}\usepackage{graphicx,caption,subfigure}\usepackage{algorithm,algpseudocode}\usepackage{amsmath,amsfonts,amssymb} \usepackage{epstopdf}\usepackage{hyperref}\usepackage{lscape}\begin{document}\begin{tabular}{|c|c|}  \hline\multirow{2}{*}{a}  & b  \\ & c \\  \hline \end{tabular}\end{document}`. provide complete small document.

Comment: Some general comments: (a) The `subfigure` package is deprecated. As you're loading the `caption` package anyway, consider loading `subcaption` instead of `subfigure`. (b) Unless your TeX distribution hasn't been updated in ca ten years, it shouldn't be necessary to load the `epstopdf` package. (c) Consider loading `pdflscape` instead of `lscape`. (d) Last but not least, be sure to load `hyperref` last. (Pun intended.)

Comment: please merge your code segment in one, complete small document as i do in my above comment: beginning by `\documentclass{...}` end ending with `\end{document}` with your table in body of document . help us to help you.

Comment: only put a tabular in `\scalebox` as an absolute last resort (and then don't do it)

Comment: I solve this by upgrading my `multirow.sty` to [newest](https://github.com/pietvo/multirow) according to [multirow | Unexpected Errors](https://latex.org/forum/viewtopic.php?t=21703).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am unable to reproduce the errors you describe, using just the scant information you've provided so far.

That said, I'd like to suggest that you redesign your table to (a) employ no vertical rules at all and (b) not using any `\multirow` directives to give the entire table a more "open" look. Separately, instead of using `\scalebox` to reduce the size, I suggest you place the tabular material in a landscape-oriented `sidewaystable` environment.

[image]

```
\documentclass{report}
% preamble simplified and streamlined
\usepackage[figuresright]{rotating}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes,arrows}
\usepackage{caption,subcaption}
\usepackage{algorithm,algpseudocode}
\usepackage{amsmath,amsfonts,amssymb}
\usepackage{pdflscape,booktabs}
\usepackage{hyperref}

\begin{document}

\begin{sidewaystable}
\centering
\begin{tabular}{@{} *{11}{c} @{}}
\toprule
S.\ No. & Subject & Session & Freq Band & Our Approach
& \multicolumn{6}{c}{Values}\\
\cmidrule(l){6-11}
& & & &
& Ours & xxxx & xxxx  & xxxx* & xxx* & xxx* \\
\midrule
\dots & \dots & \dots & \dots & \dots & \dots & \dots & \dots & \dots & \dots & \dots \\
\dots & \dots & \dots & \dots & \dots & \dots & \dots & \dots & \dots & \dots & \dots \\
\bottomrule
\end{tabular}
\end{sidewaystable}
\end{document}
```